# How to read values into 2 dimensional array in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
5
1,0,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1
0,0,0,1,1
0,1,0,1,0
1,0,0,1,1
```

I am trying to store the above values into 2-d array. My code is for this problem is given below. I don't know why it doesn't stores the values.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(n);
        String[][] multi = new String[n][n];
        int i=0;
        int t=n;
        while(t>0){
            String s=scan.nextLine();
            String b[]=s.split(",");

            for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++){

                //System.out.print(b[j]+" ");
                multi[i][j]=b[j];
            }
            //System.out.println();
                i++;
                t--;
            }
        System.out.println(multi[0][0]);
        for(int k=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                System.out.print(multi[k][j]+"  ");
                System.out.println();
            }

        }

        }
```

But it doesn't stores.Can any one help me to solve my problem.
Tell me how to do this.

Comment: Shouldn't  `for(int k=0;i<n;i++){` be `for(int k=0;k<n;k++){`

Comment: @still its not working

Comment: `scan.nextInt()` doesn't consume the newline after the "5", so you have to use `scan.nextLine()` to consume it.

Comment: I changed what you said but it is reading first line only..and also it prints that line infinately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
> for(int k=0;i<n;i++)
```

to

```
>  for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
```

**EDIT:**

Change final for loop to:

```
 for(int k=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                System.out.print(multi[k][j]+"  ");
            }
                System.out.println();
        }
```

And your final code looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    String[][] multi = new String[n][n];
    int i=0;
    int t=0;
    while(t<n){
        String s=scan.nextLine();
        String b[]=s.split("\\,");
        for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++){
            multi[i][j]=b[j];
        }
            i++;
            t++;
        }

    System.out.println(multi[0][0]);

    for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            System.out.print(multi[k][j]+"  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    }
```

Good Luck.

Comment: after changing this i got all null values.Even it doesn't prints the multi[0][0] value also

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    String[][] multi = new String[n][n];
    int i = 0;
    int t = n;

    while (t > 0) {

        String s = scan.nextLine();
        String b[] = s.split(",");

        for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
            multi[i][j] = b[j];
        }

        i++;
        t--;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.print(multi[k][j] + "  ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please replace
int n=scan.nextInt()

by int n=scan.nextLine()

Comment: i don't think you can assign `String value` to `int`